# Retrieving all records in a row in postgres with pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am writing a tool to generate reports with the help of PostgreSQL and PyQt4.

I write a query to my database like this:

```
 sql = "SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM my_table ORDER BY id ASC"
 query = QSqlQuery(self.db) # self.db holds my connection to the database
 query.exec_(sql)
```

This works fine I can now get the values from the query like this:

```
 while query.next():
    print query.record().value("field1")
```

The next step would be storing the results in a container (list/ dictionary) and do the calculations for the report. However, in my case, I have many fields which I would need to store and calling all one by one seems a long detour.

By reading about the [QSqlquery](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlquery.html) and [QSqlResult](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqlresult.html) did not bring any light. I tried with `query.result().boundValues()` but only got empty lists as return.

My expected result would be a list which holds all the values for a row.

**Question:**
This there a way to retrieve all data in a row from a query with PyQt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns in the select statement are numbered from left to right (starting from zero), so you can do:

```
indexes = range(num_cols)
while query.next():
    row = [query.value(index) for index in indexes]
```

Comment: this worked out as I expected. thanks for your insights! a little side note of funny behavior: when accidentally changing num_cols with num_rows you still get valid lists but filled with "null" values

Comment: Is there any way of getting the "num_cols" from the query object?

Comment: To get "num_cols", call query.record().count()

Answer (score 0):

```
sql=("select count(id) as total_user from datos")
query.exec_(sql)

query.next()
user=query.record().value("total_user")
self.lbl_user.setText(str(user))
```

Comment: sorry but I fail to see how this would solve my problem with many *fields*. could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer. Explain how it works.